# How to get macOS Server download code in Apple Developer Portal?

Tags: osx-server, server.app

As I recall, macOS Server used to be available to download for free via a redeem code to Apple Developers enrolled in paid Apple Developer Program. However, after the latest redesign of the Apple Developer portal during mid 2019, I'm not able to find the redeem code anymore.

It used to be possible to get the download code after logging in to the iOS Developer Center and opening the downloads page. There used to be a *Get Download Code* button which is not there anymore. Here is a picture showing how it looked like.

[image: get download code]

Now It's only possible to download the macOS server beta, but not the latest released version.

Does anyone know how can I get the redeem code nowadays?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Have you previously access the redeem code via Apple Developer Portal? If yes, the macOS Server app should be linked to your Apple ID and you should be able to re-download it for free from the Mac App Store.

Comment: I'm glad to be a part of this community. Thank you for being kind when forming my first question :) Yes I did download it in the past, and I'm still able to get it from the AppStore. However, I'm now working on a new project, belonging to a new organization where I need to set it up using a new developer account. So the state now is like I've never done it before.

Comment: If it’s only the macOS Server app that you wish to download, a slightly unconventional approach you can take is to temporarily log into Mac App Store with the Apple ID with which you previously redeemed the code, install the Server app and log out of the Mac App Store. I did try locating the redeem code in the portal myself but was unable to do so. It makes me wonder if Apple has stopped offering the app for free.

Comment: Have you tried the [developer download page](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/)?  I haven't found anything in my dev account to indicate you can get the latest version anywhere other than the MAS, even for developers.

Comment: With the Server.app being no longer offered to new users I wouldn’t be surprised if Apple stopped to provide free developer versions.

Comment: @nohillside I am suspecting the same. It appears that Apple has made this change silently, as there is no supporting reference to back.

Answer (score 1):

You can download OS X Server from the Mac App Store.  Per [this Apple Support page](https://www.apple.com/lae/osx/server/):

> OS X Server brings even more power to your business, home office, or school. Designed for OS X and iOS, OS X Server makes it easy to collaborate, develop software, host websites and wikis, configure Mac and iOS devices, and remotely access a network. It’s also remarkably simple to install, set up, and manage. **Add OS X Server to your Mac from the Mac App Store**.

I *think* the name has been changed to macOS Server but I'm not sure.  If someone knows for sure they can edit this answer.

**Update:** per discussion in comments, it appears Apple has discontinued offering a code to developers for a free copy.  All downloads, except for betas or discontinued versions, are in the MAS now and must be purchased (if applicable).

Comment: Please see the latest edit to the question. OP is seeking the redeem code which lets registered developers get macOS Server app for free from the Mac App Store. macOS Server is made available on the Mac App Store as a paid app.

Comment: [Here's](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/362136/how-to-get-macos-server-download-code-in-apple-developer-portal/362140?noredirect=1#comment480578_362140) the comment which I posted besides downvoting.

Comment: While I appreciate the explanation @NimeshNeema, my answer was posted prior to the question edit.  As I mentioned in my comment to the question, there's no place in the Developer portal to obtain a code for macOS Server.  All downloads, except for betas, are in the MAS.  So my answer was correct although it was missing info about the code.  I'll edit to add that.  A downvote was a bit harsh when you consider [what those are for](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down).

Comment: `it appears Apple has discontinued offering a code to developers for a free copy.` - Can you provide a reference to back this claim?

Comment: Yes, the reference is me.  I've looked through the developer portal and Apple Support documents.  I don't see any reference to macOS Server developer codes but I do see references directing people to the MAS for downloads.  There's nothing from Apple (that I can find) indicating it was free but is not anymore.